# If statement not working in VStack swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-playground

I am trying to display some numbers depending on a variable r0 that I have created in the view. But when I try and run my code, I get the following error: **the compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time**. Is there a way to solve this problem?

I am running this in Swift Playground

```
class MyVariables: ObservableObject {
    @Published var yourVariable = 500000.0
    @Published var otherVariable = "this will be a string"
    @Published  var slideone = 500000.0
    @Published  var slidetwo = 5000.0
    @Published var washingHandsToggle: Bool = true
    @Published var wearingMaskToggle: Bool = true
    @Published var coverMouthToggle: Bool = true
    @Published var quarantineToggle: Bool = true
    @Published var rvalues = [6.5, 5.9, 5.3, 4.8, 4.2, 3.5, 3.1, 2.9, 1.75, 1.5, 1.2, 1.05, 0.92, 0.82, 0.75, 0.7]
}


struct SecondView : View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @EnvironmentObject var model: MyVariables

    var r0 : Double {
        model.rvalues[(model.wearingMaskToggle ? 1:0) + (model.washingHandsToggle ? 2:0) + (model.quarantineToggle ? 8:0) + (model.coverMouthToggle ? 4:0)]
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
                            .font(.system(size: 30))
                            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)

                    }).padding()
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            GeometryReader { gp in
                ZStack {
                    Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "\(self.r0).jpg")!).resizable()
                        .frame(width: gp.size.width/1.15, height: gp.size.width/1.91)
                        .overlay(GeometryReader { gp in
                            VStack {
                                if self.r0 > 1 {
                                    Text("\(Int(self.model.slideone))") 
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                        .position(x: gp.size.width / 100000, y: gp.size.height / 5.55)

                                    Text("\(Int((self.model.slideone - self.model.slidetwo)/2))")
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                        .position(x: gp.size.width / 100000)
                                        .padding(.top, gp.size.height/4.75)

                                    Text("\(Int(self.model.slidetwo))")
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                        .position(x: gp.size.width / 100000, y: gp.size.height / 22.5)
                                        .padding(.top, gp.size.height/5.675)
                                } else{
                                    Text("\(Int(self.model.slidetwo))") 
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                        .position(x: gp.size.width / 100000, y: gp.size.height / 5.55)

                                    Text("\(Int(self.model.slidetwo/2))")
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                        .position(x: gp.size.width / 100000)
                                        .padding(.top, gp.size.height/4.75)
                                }
                            }
                            VStack {
                                HStack {
                                    Text("10") 
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                        .position(x: gp.size.width / 5.75, y: gp.size.height / 1.0675)

                                    Text("20") 
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                        .position(x: gp.size.width / 5.75, y: gp.size.height / 1.0675)

                                    Text("20") 
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                        .position(x: gp.size.width / 6.65, y: gp.size.height / 1.0675)

                                    Text("30") 
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                        .position(x: gp.size.width / 8.2, y: gp.size.height / 1.0675)

                                    Text("40") 
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                        .position(x: gp.size.width / 10.4, y: gp.size.height / 1.0675)

                                    Text("50") 
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                        .position(x: gp.size.width / 14.5, y: gp.size.height / 1.0675)

                                    Text("60") 
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                        .position(x: gp.size.width / 22.5, y: gp.size.height / 1.0675)

                                    Text("70") 
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                                        .position(x: gp.size.width / 56, y: gp.size.height / 1.0675)
                                }
                            }
                            }
                    )
                }.padding(.leading, gp.size.width / 15)
                Spacer()
            }
        }.background(Color.white)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just break that enormous body on subviews|functions|etc. apart. Try to make each not more than 40 lines - it will be ideal.

Comment: @Asperi How would I do that for this code?

Comment: Please show how you defined MyVariables.  Where do you get the error exactly ? Usually, explicitly declaring the type of var solves the compiler type check issue.

Comment: @claude31 ok I added it to the code

Comment: Thanks, but how is ContentView defined ? Please post code so that we can replicate problem without too much extra work. Important: where exactly do you get the error ?

Comment: You have too many views you should separate the parts under the if statement into their own separate swift UI views and the compiler will not have to do so much work. When you have many lines of code in the same swift UI view since swift is a reactive language it will cause it to be slow. Also, you are less error-prone if you use better variable names and break up your views.